# JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data

Tags: javascript, nodejs, angular

Estoy aprendiendo Angular con NodeJS y tengo unos problemas que me surgen a partir de una subida de archivos, en este caso, imágenes.

La idea es crear un formulario con algunos campos, dentro de esos campos un título y una descripción que funcionan bien.

El tema es al momento de asignarle una imagen al objeto JSON.
La idea es, hacer click en el botón de subir la imagen, abrir la ventana, buscar la imagen y que la guarde en el servidor (por el momento, local), para luego darle click al botón de guardado, y que, en el caso de la imagen, que guarde la ubicación.

Estoy usando Angular Image Uploader, peor me salen problemas en la consola a la hora de subir una imagen, sobre todo en el método `imageUpload`

El método `imageUpload` está incompleto, pero la idea es que al menos salte el `alert`, pero no lo hace, sin embargo, guarda la imagen en el servidor, por lo que estimo que el backend funciona correctamente en ese caso.

```
JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
```

El código que estoy usando es el siguiente:

EN LA VISTA DE ANGULAR:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <angular-file-uploader
        [config]="afuConfig"
        (ApiResponse)="imageUpload($event)"
     ></angular-file-uploader>
</div>
```

EN EL COMPONENT.TS de la vista:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { Article } from '../../models/article';
import { ArticleService } from '../../services/article.service';
import { Global } from '../../services/global';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-article-new',
  templateUrl: './article-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./article-new.component.css'],
  providers: [ArticleService]
})
export class ArticleNewComponent implements OnInit {
    public article: Article;    
  public status: string;

  afuConfig = {
    multiple: false,
    formatsAllowed: ".jpg, .png, .gif, .jpeg",
    maxSize: "50",
    uploadAPI:  {
      url: Global.url+'upload-image'
    },
    theme: "attachPin",
    hideProgressBar: true,
    hideResetBtn: true,
    hideSelectBtn: false,
    replaceTexts: {
      selectFileBtn: 'Select Files',
      resetBtn: 'Reset',
      uploadBtn: 'Upload',
      dragNDropBox: 'Drag N Drop',
      attachPinBtn: 'Sube la Imagen del Artículo',
      afterUploadMsg_success: 'Successfully Uploaded !',
      afterUploadMsg_error: 'Upload Failed !'
    }
};

  constructor(
    private _route: ActivatedRoute,
    private _router: Router,
    private _articleService: ArticleService
    ) {
    this.article = new Article('','','', null, null);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onSubmit(){
    this._articleService.create(this.article).subscribe(
      response => {
        if(response.status == 'success'){
          this.status = 'success';
          this.article = response.article;
          this._router.navigate(['/blog']);
        }else{
          this.status = 'error';
        }

      },
      error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.status = 'error';
      }
    );
  }

  imageUpload(data){
    let image_data = JSON.parse(data.response);
    alert(image_data.image);
  }

}
```

Este es mi BACKEND de nodejs:

```
upload: (req, res) => {
        // Configurar el modulo connect multiparty router/article.js (hecho)

        // Recoger el fichero de la petición
        var file_name = 'Imagen no subida...';

        if(!req.files){
            return res.status(404).send({
                status: 'error',
                message: file_name
            });
        }

        // Conseguir nombre y la extensión del archivo
        var file_path = req.files.file0.path;
        var file_split = file_path.split('\\');

        // Nombre del archivo
        var file_name = file_split[2];

        // Extensión del fichero
        var extension_split = file_name.split('\.');
        var file_ext = extension_split[1];

        // Comprobar la extension, solo imagenes, si es valida borrar el fichero
        if(file_ext != 'png' && file_ext != 'jpg' && file_ext != 'jpeg' && file_ext != 'gif'){

            // borrar el archivo subido
            fs.unlink(file_path, (err) => {
                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'error',
                    message: 'La extensión de la imagen no es válida !!!'
                });
            });

        }else{
             // Si todo es valido, sacando id de la url
             var articleId = req.params.id;

             if(articleId){
                // Buscar el articulo, asignarle el nombre de la imagen y actualizarlo
                Article.findOneAndUpdate({_id: articleId}, {image: file_name}, {new:true}, (err, articleUpdated) => {

                    if(err || !articleUpdated){
                        return res.status(200).send({
                            status: 'error',
                            message: 'Error al guardar la imagen de articulo !!!'
                        });
                    }

                    return res.status(200).send({
                        status: 'success',
                        article: articleUpdated
                    });
                });
             }else{
                return res.status(200).send({
                    status: 'success',
                    image: file_name
                });
             }

        }   
    }, // end upload file
```

ESTA ES LA PARTE DE SERVICE en la que se crean los registros:

```
create(article):Observable<any>{
        let params = JSON.stringify(article);
        let headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this._http.post(this.url+'save', params, {headers: headers});
    }


}
```

Comment: No puedes convertir una imagen a `JSON`. Creo que `data`, es un tipo `File`. Haz como dice @FrancoDreher, pon un `console.log`. De todas formas no vas a poder mandar tu imagen. Necesitas crear un `FormData` y copiar todos tus datos a el.

Comment: Lo que estoy haciendo es tomar la ubicación del archivo y pasarlo a JSON, mientras la imagen sube al servidor, estaría guardando la ubicación en el objeto JSON, esa sería la idea.
El `console.log` me tira el objeto con el `status: success` y el nombre del archivo guardado en el servidor.